# Google Firebase username registration

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I started using Google's Firebase because, as you know, Parse is shutting down :-/
but I'm so lost in it.

I'm using [registration by email / password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) and it is all good, but I want to add a simple username (not an email address) to this.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Firebase Authentication does not have an API to add custom properties to a user profile. Most developers solve this problem by storing user information in the Firebase Database under a `/users/<userId>` structure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523841/how-do-i-store-more-information-in-firebase-for-a-user-than-the-auth-module-allo

Answer (score 1):

You can add the username field on the input form on your client and then, after the standard email / password authentication process is completed, use Firebase Database to store the user informations in the path `/users/<uid>`, adding the username and all the other fields you need.